# Determining for how long a thread has been running

Tags: c#, multithreading, c#-4.0, timer

I need a logic that would allow me to do something when a thread is running for more that X amount of seconds.

Like in this incredibly ugly example, here it will check every second and if the `workerThread` is running for 10 or more minutes it shows a message...

```
var timeWorking = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(0);
workerThread = new Thread(RunTask);
workerThread.Start(task);
while (workerThread.IsAlive)
{
    Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
    timeWorking = timeWorking.Add(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1));
    if (timeWorking.TotalMinutes < 10) continue;
    timeWorking = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(0);
    Console.Writeline("Here we go... the event")
}
```

Please help me to make it right... 
What should I use `Diagnostics.StopWatch`, `System.Timers.Timer` or `Threading.Timer` ?

UPD: All the answers confused me even more...

The task is to check if `workerThread` is running for more than X amount of time, and if it is, call some method, reset the timer and check again if `workerThread` now is running for more than X amount of time since the last time we called the method... and so on and on...

UPD2: Basically I have a thread that does a processing based on information pulled from AmazonSQS queue. SQS Queue message has a visibility timeout. If the task will take longer than default visibility timeout - the message will be back to the queue before the task has finished. And then it will be picked up by another machine. To avoid that I need to extend visibility timeout of SQS message. 
So I can do that by checking periodically if thread stil `isALive` then I can add couple of minutes to the message visibility timeout. After a minute and 50 seconds or so, I should check again and if thread still `isALive` then add couple more minutes and so on.

Comment: Do you want time thread used CPU (scheduled for execution) or elapsed time as in your current sample?

Comment: Side note: expecting Sleep to provide precise delay is wrong assumption - the only guarantee Sleep makes is that thread will not be woken up before requested time, it may sleep longer - so adding second to "timeWorking" will always be less then actual elapsed time.

Answer (score 2):

I think [System.Timers.Timer](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timers.timer.aspx) is better suited based on what you've described.  But, it depends.  If you want to do something with the UI with the timer.  Forms.Timer is better.

In either case, you could simply check if the thread is still alive when the timer Elapsed (or Ticked) and do something if it is.

e.g.

```
    timeThreadStarted = DateTime.Now;
    workerThread = new Thread(RunTask);
    System.Timers.Timer timer = new System.Timers.Timer(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1).TotalMilliseconds);
    timer.Elapsed += new System.Timers.ElapsedEventHandler(timer_Elapsed);
    workerThread.Start(task);
//...

static void timer_Elapsed(object sender, System.Timers.ElapsedEventArgs e)
{
    if(workerThread != null && workerThread.IsAlive)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("thread has been running for {0}!", DateTime.Now - timeThreadStarted);
    }
}
```

This checks the thread state after 1 second.  If it is still Alive then it has been running for at least one second.

This has the benefit of not blocking any threads.  If you have a UI and you want to do this, then you can't block the UI Thread (it will become unresponsive and provide a poor user experience).

Answer (score 2):

Since you know that the thread needs to do something after ten minutes, why not simply use an interval on the timer like this:

```
var interval = 1000 * 60 * 10; // ten minutes
var timer = new System.Timers.Timer(interval) { AutoReset = false };
timer.Elapsed += ((sender, eventArgs) =>
    {
        // Do your work here...
    });

workerThread = new Thread(RunTask);
workerThread.Start(task);
timer.Start();
```

This way you are not checking each second and you will execute your code after a desired amount of time.

Comment: Does it matter if you get the total time by polling or after the thread has completed its task or ended via the `Timer`?  If this were me I would calculate the time when the worker thread finishes its work or when the `Timer.Elapsed` event fires. If you are updating the UI with this value I would still fake it by incrementing every second and only update after one of those events fire.  This way you are not slowing down the worker thread.

Answer (score 1):

You could also do `Thread.Join` with a `TimeSpan` like the example at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/23f7b1ct.aspx so that you don't have to do a `Thread.Sleep`.

Note: either approach blocks calling thread until the time has elapsed. Not suitable for main/UI threads.

Comment: This also blocks one thread to wait for another, probably not what is needed, especially if this check is performed on the main/UI thread.

Comment: +1 Join is better way to implement original blocking code. Both are clearly not suitable for UI threads.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a Timer that will raise an event once the elapsed time as triggered.

```
 private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var thread = new Thread(
            () =>
                {
                    var timer = new System.Timers.Timer
                        {
                            Interval = 10000, //10s
                            AutoReset = false, //only raise the elapsed event once
                        };
                    timer.Elapsed += timer_Elapsed;
                    timer.Start();
                    while (true)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine("Running...");
                        Thread.Sleep(1000); //Always put a thread to sleep when its blocking so it does not waste CPU cycles.
                    }
                });
        thread.Start();
    }

    private static void timer_Elapsed(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
    {
        //thread is running for more that X (10s) amount of seconds
        Console.WriteLine("Timer elapsed");
    }
```

That is a simple example. In this example, the thread never exits. But you can add your own logic where necessary to get what you are trying to accomplish.

Short answer: Yes, use System.Timers.Timer

Comment: +0: I think it is backwards to what OP wanted as it uses Timer on child thread (also using timer in general is good idea).

Answer (score -2):

You can use the Task wait method, for example

```
var t = Task.Factory.StartNew(() => MyAction()); // MyAction is an action to be executed in parallel


bool check = t.Wait(10000); //wait for 10000 milliseconds
if (check)
{
 // all ok
}
else 
{
  // over time 
}
```

The Wait method blocks until the task ends or timeout happens. If you don't want to block your primary thread, you can run the example code using another task that works in parallel and checks the working task.

Comment: That would block the current thread, where a `Timer` would allow you to not block the thread...  Not good if performed on the Main/UI thread.

Comment: see my edited response, the code can be executed in another task.

Comment: look at the question. A task can be used to check other tasks, like timers, but the task run once, Timer is more useful if you want to perform a check many times, but this is not the question.